# Pytorch BertForSequenceClassification model always predicts 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model

I am using Bert on the https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/deepcontractor/supreme-court-judgment-prediction dataset to perform binary classification and am having problems with my model predicting all 0's. I recognized this 2/3 of my data was 0 labels vs 1 and my accuracy was always 67% no matter the parameters I tweaked, and when I switched to 50/50 0's and 1 labels my accuracy went to 50%, indicating my model is only predicting one of the variables.

Here is my preprocessing and preparing code:

```py
cases = pd.read_csv("justice.csv")
cases.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0', 'ID', 'name', 'href', 'docket', 'term',  
                    'majority_vote', 'minority_vote', 'decision_type', 'disposition', 'issue_area'], inplace=True)
cases.dropna(inplace=True)

cases = cases.rename(columns={'first_party_winner': 'winning_party_idx'})
for i, row in cases.iterrows():
    if row['winning_party_idx'] == True:
        cases.loc[i, 'winning_party_idx'] = 0
    else:
        cases.loc[i, 'winning_party_idx'] = 1

# Create a mirrored case for each case, where the parties are swapped to prevent favoring first_party
mirrored_cases = cases.copy()
mirrored_cases['first_party'], mirrored_cases['second_party'] = mirrored_cases['second_party'], mirrored_cases['first_party']
mirrored_cases['winning_party_idx'] = (mirrored_cases['winning_party_idx'] == 0).astype(int)
mirrored_cases.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

cases = pd.concat([cases, mirrored_cases])
cases.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

cases['facts'] = cases['facts'].str.replace(r'<[^<]+?>', '', regex=True)
cases['facts'] = cases['facts'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\'\s]', '', x))
#cases['facts'] = cases['facts'].str.lower()

def word_count(text):
  return len(text.split())

cases['facts_len'] = cases['facts'].apply(word_count)
cases['facts_len'].describe()

cases['facts'] = cases.loc[cases['facts_len'] <= 390, 'facts']
cases['facts'] = cases.apply(lambda x: f"{x['first_party']} [SEP] {x['second_party']} [SEP] {x['facts']}", axis=1)
cases = cases.drop(columns=['first_party', 'second_party', 'facts_len'])

train_facts, val_facts, train_winners,  val_winners = train_test_split(
    cases['facts'], cases['winning_party_idx'], test_size=0.20)

train_facts, val_facts = train_facts.tolist(), val_facts.tolist()
train_winners, val_winners = [str(i) for i in train_winners], [str(i) for i in val_winners]

#leave truncate flag off to ensure that no data is truncated
#if data is too large this code will not run
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
train_encodings = tokenizer(train_facts, padding=True)
val_encodings = tokenizer(val_facts, padding=True)

class TextDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor(int(self.labels[idx]))
        type(item)
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

train_dataset = TextDataset(train_encodings, train_winners)
val_dataset = TextDataset(val_encodings, val_winners)
```

And here is the code to load and train the model:

```py
#Load pretrained model
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased', 
                                                      num_labels=2, 
                                                      hidden_dropout_prob=0.4,
                                                      attention_probs_dropout_prob=0.4)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="test_trainer", 
    logging_dir='logs', 
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,  
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    logging_steps=50,
)
metric = evaluate.load("accuracy")
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()
```

If anyone has any insight as to why my model seems to be failing to make predictions I would greatly appreciate it! I was thinking it could be an issue with the loss function but I am unclear what the default loss function is here or how to properly override it for this case.

Comment: There can be a few reason to why your model is only predicting 0's. I don't think that the loss function is a problem because the default loss function is cross entropy which is okay  for classification problems. check your preprocessing to make sure that it doesn't corrupt your data.  You can first try to train your model on a smaller dataset just to make sure it works.